# Query Starter mirroring our Q/A sites

Tags: discussion

I was googling for my own answer from couple of years ago and was surprised to first find it from an Indian site called "Query Starter" https://www.questarter.com/

This site seems to mirror all questions from several SE sites, but not in realtime. I wouldn't mind if it was stated clearly that they are providing e.g. an accessibility interface or a proxy for slow local connections for enabling access to these sites via Stack Exchange API. Sharing the information is even encouraged:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

But it's not. It's just all our content with added `Copyright © QueStarter 2019`.

Is SE aware of it already? How SE handles copyright infringement in general?

Comment: Thanks, @JennyD! I've sent a notification to the site owner with `Cc: <legal@stackoverflow.com>`. I'll remove this as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, sometimes asking politely helps: the site now has `user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0, source Stack Overflow` in its footer. That's satisfactory.